# custom windows credential provider azure ad

Tags: azure, active-directory, winlogon, credential-providers

I created my own implementation of `ICredentialProvider` and `ICredentialProviderCredential` for Windows [sample code](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/V2-Credential-Provider-7549a730)) , so I can use my own process to login in windows [REF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/mt158211(v=vs.85).aspx#custom_credential_providers).

It works with credentials from a simple Windows user account, but for credentials from users related to an `Azure Active Directory` (Azure AD) it doesn't work.

Is it possible to hand over the credentials direct to azure ad to login in Windows?

Or does anybody know where I can find sample code or a description for a own windows credential provider that use azure ad?

Comment: Stuck with the same problem, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You must manage all users in CP.
[Credential provider not displayed for all users (Other user included)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55967533/credential-provider-not-displayed-for-all-users-other-user-included)

And this is very good Full sample for you
https://github.com/multiOTP/multiOTPCredentialProvider

Answer (score 1):

Use domain name as "AzureAd" and username as test@azuredomain.com.
So , when you want to login Azure AD user in customized credential provider use username as AzureAd\test@azuredomain.com .